# Cannot index columns in two dataframes in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to index columns in two different dataframes and there appears to be a mismatch in columns so it makes sense that I keep getting an error. A chunk of the code I am looking to use is the following:

`df_3 = df_3[df_1.columns] df = pd.concat([df_1,df_3])`

I know you cannot concatenate them until it is a 1:1 match, but I am confused primarily on the first line of code - can somebody define what "df_3 = df_3[df_1.columns]" is doing before it concatenates? This will help me insert the proper columns into the proper dataframes. (I am a beginner in case you couldn't notice)

When I typically run the code above it gives me the following error:

KeyError: "['STATUS', 'ID', 'ATTEMPT', 'TYPE'] not in index"

Comment: What is it doing? It is a projection. It will succeed if DF1 has a subset of DF3’s columns. The spelling of column names must match exactly between the two data frames. Put another way, DF3 must have a superset of the DF1 column names.

Comment: I gotcha. I basically wanted to know which one would be the superset vs the subset. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> define what "df_3 = df_3[df_1.columns]" is doing ... ?

Suppose that `df_3` has columns a, b, c, d. And `df_1` has just a, b, c columns.

Then `df_1.columns` will be `['a', 'b', 'c']`.
And the expression you mentioned will project down
from 4 columns to just 3, eliding `'d'`.

In general, the expression `df[some_list]`, such as `df[['a', 'b', 'c']]`,
will [project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)#Example) down to the columns mentioned in that list.

It is important that the original dataframe have all of those
mentioned column names, or else an error will be raised.
Use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)
beforehand if you're unsure of which columns will be present.